# Show Hebrew Months in UIDatePicker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, uidatepicker

Is there a way to show hebrew month names in a UIDatePicker instead of Gregorian ones? How? Can this be set programmatically?

Comment: Beware of leap years and month numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `UIDatePicker` that prevents it from correctly honoring the `calendar` property (which is how you're supposed to do this).  Please [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IB to create your view you can add a `UIDatePicker` and set its Locale property to "Hebrew".

[image]

Comment: I want to show the hebrew names of the months, not the gregorian months in hebrew letters.

Comment: "locale" property is deprecated in latest iOS

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, however you can create your own `UIPickerView` to display hebrew months instead.

It looks like `UIDatePicker` has this property but has now been deprecated for ios 5.0

```
locale
The locale used by the date picker. (Deprecated in iOS 5.0.)

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSLocale *locale
```

Comment: I think you can set the `calendar` property.