# "unknown" year in UIDatePicker without custom UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I fear this has been asked, and shot down many times, but it's worth a shot...

Is it possible to use create a UIDatePicker exactly the same as the birthday picker in the Contacts App, with the option of "----" for the year component, without recreating it all with a UIPickerView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No. `UIDatePicker` will always display the year.

Comment: I thought this may be the case. Thanks

Comment: @leon NP. It's fairly trivial to create your own custom date picker if you are not particularly worried about internationalization (if you are, then it becomes more complicated). Check out this SO Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004778/how-do-i-rewrite-the-uidatepicker-component